# prompt missing running delve using gud in emacs?

Tags: debugging, go, emacs, delve

Here is the experience running delve from the command line on my Windows 10 desktop using MSYS-2:

[image]

Now here is the experience running delve from GNU emacs (W64) version 25.1.1 -
ShellPrompt> emacs -nw H:/code/Go/book/chap1_lissajous/lissajous.go
C-x-2
M-x dlv
Run dlv (like this): dlv debug H:/code/Go/book/chap1_lissajous/lissajous.go
Navigate to lissajous.go:34 and hit C-x-C-a-C-b to toggle a breakpoint
Navigate to dlv buffer
Hit 'c', and the experience looks like this for this entire interaction:

[image]

Notice the absence of **(dlv)** in front of the c (continue) command when running using emacs. The result is the same using emacs in non-terminal mode as well.

I tried to find any gud customizations that needed to be applied for the prompt to show up. I could not find any, and I was unable to find anyone else facing this issue online. Does anybody know if I am missing something?

NOTE: I have had to post images instead of formatted text because I couldn't figure how to get markdown to render the code in a formatted way with the line numbers from the debugger. I wasn't allowed to post the question with unformatted code. I apologize to those who are only able to view the text of my post and not the images. The images are needed to view the question completely.

Comment: Thanks @Flimzy for making the edits. Appreciate it.